# Upgrading from windows 7 to 10 makes my pc turn off on high load

Tags: windows-7, windows, windows-10, cpu, fan

Yesterday I updated my version of windows from my old 7 installation to windows 10 home edition via a clean install. Since then I've mainly been busy installing the programs I need for the various things I do on my pc. Most of them involve heavy CPU load (like Livestreaming, Recording, Music Production, Video editing & Rendering). Up until yesterday I never had issues with my PC turning off when these things happened though but ever since I updated after just 5 minutes of livestreaming my PC turned off.

I've checked the temperatures and they are pretty high (Peak 71 Celsius) but from what I remember, your PC should only turn off when your CPU hits 90 Celsius (Is this information right?).

I've tried a few things to reduce the temparature:

- Turn my fan profile to high in BIOS settings
- Turn power profile to high preformance in BIOS settings (should also upp the CPU fan speed I think.)
- Turn down CPU usage from 100% to 95% in windows power settings (I've heard 100% CPU usage can cause these problems. )

My (Relevant) hardware:

```
AMD FX-8350
Stock cooler
ASUS M5A97 EVO R2.0 Motherboard
Corsair CX600M PSU
```

What can I do to stop this from happening? Could upgrading to windows 10 have caused a problem with my cooling? if not, why would it not happen on windows 7?

Comment: Update BIOS and all your Drivers, especially Video and Power. The Windows 10 install may not have installed all drivers for your particular machine.

Comment: @John I'm installing video card drivers now, thanks for that! What exactly do you mean by Power Drivers?

Comment: Your computer may not have specific power drivers. Look on the manufacturer's support site. If not, do not worry about Power Drivers.

Comment: @John I build it myself, do I look for motherboard or PSU manufacturer?

Comment: Look at the motherboard specs

Comment: Also, fans are cheap.  Add more fans to pull air in and push air out of your box.  Make sure the air flow is consistent, typically pull in from the front, out to the back.

Comment: @SeñorCMasMas I'm thinking of replacing my stock cooler with a better one as it seems only my CPU is really hot.